# TException:MISSING_RESULT thrift exception on T_COMPACT_PROTOCOL asynchrounsly thrift client call

Tags: thrift, thrift-protocol

I'm using C++ asynchronously thrift for IPC inside my application.
One client of my thrift is connected to the server using `T_PROTOCOL_COMPACT` protocol using `TCompactProtocolFactory` (and of course the transport is `TAsioTcpConnectServerTransport`).

I do see that my client is being connected successfully to the server.

**Client side:**

```
2024-01-29 09:23:40,636 INFO  [0x7ffff53576c0] ClientEventHandler<Interface> (../../src/ipc/thrift/AsyncThriftClient.tpp:68) 229 - "Function":"onConnect", "Event":"ASYNC_THRIFT_CLIENT_ON_CONNECT", "Message":"Client connects to the server", "ServiceName":"MulpiSvcClient.10.244.22.229", "RemoteEndpoint":"10.244.22.229:23501"
2024-01-29 09:23:40,636 INFO  [0x7ffff53576c0] ClientEventHandler<Interface> (../../src/ipc/thrift/AsyncThriftClient.tpp:75) 229 - "Function":"onConnect", "Event":"ASYNC_THRIFT_CLIENT_ON_CONNECT", "Message":"Client was created successfully to the server"
```

**Server side**

```
2024-01-29T09:23:40.636009637Z {"Role": "active", "Severity": "INFO", "Package": "server", "Version" : "1.48-598.2", "File": "ThriftServiceManager.hpp:25", "Logger": "server.api", "Function": "onConnect", Connected local=[::ffff:10.244.22.228]:23501 remote=[::ffff:10.244.22.253]:52436}
```

But I see that sometimes the call is successful but in most time I get TException thrown.

```
Thrift: Mon Jan 29 09:22:01 2024 Unhandled exception MISSING_RESULT Exception: 'GetOfdmaCmMerData'
```

I will add also a screenshot from PCAP file I've captured on the client side.
[image]

Is there any reason why this can be happening? Is it because the server side drops the client request or maybe the client didn't waited enough for the server response?

**EDIT:**
Adding here logs from successful call

```
2024-01-29T09:47:38.293726795Z {"Severity": "ERROR", "Package": "client", "Version" : "1.0-21", "File": "../../src/external-interfaces/mulpi/clientInterface.cpp", "Line": "272", "Function": "GetOfdmaCmMerData", "Event":"EXT_IFACES_MULPI_GET_OFDMA_CHANNEL_DATA", "Message":"GetOfdmaCmMerData", "Id":"0x1000000", "subId":"0x29", "serverIp":"10.244.22.229", "mdOfdmaCmMerDataFetchSize:":"MdOfdmaCmMerData {
2024-01-29T09:47:38.293762061Z   Id: 16777216
2024-01-29T09:47:38.293769181Z   SubId: 0
2024-01-29T09:47:38.293773881Z   ofdmaCmMerData: OfdmaCmMerData {
2024-01-29T09:47:38.293778161Z   mslotsInfo: 
2024-01-29T09:47:38.293782125Z     Key: 0, Value: MinislotInfo {
2024-01-29T09:47:38.293785868Z   index: 0
2024-01-29T09:47:38.293789721Z   lowerFreq: 39000000
2024-01-29T09:47:38.293793793Z }
2024-01-29T09:47:38.293797520Z     Key: 1, Value: MinislotInfo {
2024-01-29T09:47:38.293801191Z   index: 1
2024-01-29T09:47:38.293805018Z   lowerFreq: 39400000
2024-01-29T09:47:38.293808412Z }
2024-01-29T09:47:38.293812383Z     Key: 2, Value: MinislotInfo {
2024-01-29T09:47:38.293816468Z   index: 2
2024-01-29T09:47:38.293820141Z   lowerFreq: 39800000
2024-01-29T09:47:38.293823760Z }
...
2024-01-29T09:47:38.302070699Z     Key: 170, Value: MinislotInfo {
2024-01-29T09:47:38.302074986Z   index: 170
2024-01-29T09:47:38.302079187Z   lowerFreq: 107000000
2024-01-29T09:47:38.302083072Z }
2024-01-29T09:47:38.302087105Z   mers: 
2024-01-29T09:47:38.302091026Z }
```

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED:**
The issue was that the connection was sometimes opened to server with same THRIFT IFACE but with different IP which doesn't have the requested data inside it.